# Unity (C#) — Как оптимизировать Android игру под различные экраны?

Tags: android, c#, unity3d

Есть ли какие-либо автоматические способы изменять размер фона/спрайтов под различные экраны или нужно делать в ручную? Если в ручную то как именно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы спрашиваете об объектах на игровой сцене, то самый простой вариант решения проблемы - поднимать камеру :) т.е при старте рассчитывайте разрешение экрана и поднимайте камеру до уровня, когда всё будет помещаться.
Чтобы не было каких-то "пустых" участков, можете расширить поле каким-то "затычками".

Если вы говорите про интерфейс, то вам в помощь компонент CanvasScaler и настройка якорей (anchor). У Unity есть [небольшой мануал](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html) на эту тему

Comment: Спасибо. Нужно было узнать и то, и то)

Comment: @Артём, если вопрос решён - пометьте ответ, как решающий) это закроет вопрос.